# A formula can't display properly in comment only

Tags: bug, mathjax, comment

The term $\chi_{{}^{*}P}({}^{*}r)$ can display properly in the question, but when I paste it in a comment, it become something like:
[image]

which is the same as \chi_{{}^{*}P}({}^{*}r), when $$ eliminated.

The code is:

[image]

I've tried it on Firefox, and Chrome, and there's no difference. What is wrong?

Comment: $\chi_{{}^{*}P}({}^{*}r)$

Comment: Needs a space: $\chi_{{}^{}P} ({}^{}r)$

Comment: @J.M. I'm not sure. There's no problem in displaying $\chi_P(r)$. But when I want to add a star to $P$ and $r$, it's kind of different.

Comment: Use `\ast`. $P\ast q$

Comment: @J.M. Ah,yes!! That works. Thank you.

Comment: @J.M.: I think this is useful information. Why don't you promote your comment to an answer?

Comment: @rob, I was hoping Metta can answer his own question now. Oh well...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `\ast` seems to work nicely, as `\chi_{{}^{\ast}P}({}^{\ast}r)` gives $\chi_{{}^{\ast}P}({}^{\ast}r)$

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the interaction of Markdown being performed before MathJax runs, so the two stars end up being turned into marks for italics, and MathJax doesn't process the equation because it contains internal HTML.  J.M.'s solution gets you around that.  You could also use `\*` since that will prevent Markdown from processing the star (and also remove the `\` so that it is just a `*` when MathJax sees it).

Note that you don't need to do this in the question or answer (just comments), because the comments use a different processor than questions and answers.  The Q&A processor has a much more sophisticated understanding of the interaction between MathJax and Markdown, and protects math from Markdown processing.